# react-native - what is the different <View> or <>?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Are there any differences between   and <> </>?

When using  I have to import the 'react-native' package

`import { View } from 'react-native'`

no when using <> </>

```
<View>
 <FirstComponent/>
 <SeconComponent/>
</View>
```

```
<>
 <FirstComponent/>
 <SeconComponent/>
</>
```

they are similar?

Answer (score 6):

They are not. `View` is a component that can be counted as an element while `<>` also known as `Fragment`, act like a wrapper but it's not an element.

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
  <View>
    <FirstComponent />
    <SecondComponent />
  </View>
</View>
```

For the code above, you will see `SecondComponent` directly beside `FirstComponent`

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
  <>
    <FirstComponent />
    <SecondComponent />
  </>
</View>
```

For the example above, you will see a big gap between `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent`.

`Fragment` is often being used because you want to logically group the elements together but don't want to mess up the styling due to extra layer such as below

```js
// wish to return both `FirstComponent` & `SecondComponent`, but you can't without Fragment

const renderComponent = () => {
  //return <FirstComponent /><SecondComponent /> // <<== this is invalid
  return <><FirstComponent/><SecondComponent /></> // similar result as above 
}

<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
  {renderComponent()}
</View>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference in  and <></> statements.

Everything in one view element is considered and one element for parent tag. But if you use Fragment(<></>). All the tags under fragment will be consider as separate element.

Answer (score 2):

<></> is a shortcut for <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
It is different from  as it does not create a DOM element.

You can find more about Fragments here https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html